# How to write "There is v in set W and P, such that v is in set P"?

Tags: notation

How to write "There is v in set W and P, such that v is in P"?

I thought of the following possibilities:

```
∃ v ∈ W : ( ∃ P : v ∈ P)
```

or

```
∃ v ∈ W, P : v ∈ P
```

Is either of these correct? If not, how should I write it?

Comment: Your title does not match what you asked. Which is the intended question?

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. I just couldn't write the ∄ symbol, so I switched to ∃.

Comment: Without some constraints on $v$, $W$ and $P$ both sentences are obviously true: for each $v$, despite belonging to $W$ or not, there exist such $P$, that $v\in P$ — namely a singleton $P=\{v\}$, and there exist such $Q$ that $v\notin Q$ — for example the empty set $Q=\{\}$.

Comment: @CiaPan, You're right, but that's irrelevant to the question... I just want to know how to represent the idea with mathematical symbols...

Comment: @EduardoBezerra That gets an answer. This got a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:
$$\exists v \in W : v \in P$$
Another, equivalent expression is:
$$\exists v \in W \cap P : v \in P$$

Answer (score -1):

You can write *'there is no such P'* in several ways. Directly
$$\not\exists P : v\in P$$
or *'it's not true there exist such P'*:
$$\neg\left(\exists P : v\in P\right)$$
or even by transferring the negation into the predicate, as *'for each P, v can't belong to P'*:
$$\forall P : v\notin P$$